# How to remove a line from a file in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a file, It has a line

> DocumentRoot path/to/folder

I have to remove this line, What should be the regular expression. ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do with http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html:

```
- lineinfile: 
    dest: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default 
    state: absent 
    regexp: "^DocumentRoot"
```

or http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html:

```
- replace: 
    dest: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
    regexp: "^DocumentRoot"    
    regexp: '^(DocumentRoot)\s+[^\n]*\n$' 
    replace: '#\1'  
    validate: '/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -f %s -t'
```

PS:

But I didn't check if regexp's were right =)
Also you can use template module:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html
or template and assemble module:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/assemble_module.html

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html

Regex: `"^DocumentRoot path/to/folder$"`